# How is it possible in Android to upload media from mobile to server whenever network is available?

Tags: android, upload

I am working on an Android application in which the mobile will capture images and videos and save to the phone memory. I need to upload these media to GCS when there is connectivity to internet. I think, using broadcast receiver is an option to check the connectivity and upload the media. But I am not sure about how to implement that. Could someone suggest me a better way to do the upload whenever the network is available?

Comment: Just use a simple Timer.Check network every servel seconds.It's a bad but easy way,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BroadcastReceiver` is the best option to identify connectivity changes.

Check out the official android documentation about [Determining and Monitoring the Connectivity Status](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html).

Then it is suggested to identify when the user is connected to WiFi network and use some-kind of `Service` to upload your data.

At the official site there is a lot of resources about [Building Apps with Connectivity & the Cloud](http://developer.android.com/training/building-connectivity.html).

Or you can simply search out better ways to [upload data programmatically in Android](https://www.google.gr/search?q=upload+data+programmatically+in+Android).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I have implemented the same thing for checking the network changes..